# Insert ceros instead of interopolate ARIMA_PLUS bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to do ARIMA_plus forecasting on a series of sale records. The problem is that sale records only contain sales. When  doing the forecast we need to insert for every product the "non sales", which, essentially, are rows with the import column set to cero for every day the product has not been sold. We have here two options:

1. Fill the database with those zero-rows (uses a lot of space)
2. When doing the forecasting with ARIMA_PLUS in bigquery tell the model to fill with zeros instead of interpolating (default and seemingly unique option).

I want to follow the second option, yet, i dont see how. Here you can see a screenshot of the documentation [Google info about interpolation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tONAb.png)

The first option would be carried out with a merge, nevertheless I would prefer to discard it since it increases the size of the sales table.

I have scanned the documentation and havent seen any solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an input dataset covering the missing values with the right method for your use case.

In other words, the SQL query must solve the interpolation so that the input for the model already contains the expected data.

You can, for example, create a query to add a liner interpolation solution for your use case.

So, the first approach you mentioned can be solved using that input SQL (rather than adding the data to the source table) and the second approach is not valid in bigquery, as far as I know.

Here you have an example: https://justrocketscience.com/post/interpolation_sql/

Comment: Thanks David, but the input for the model does not necessarily need to contain the expected data. In fact my question relates precisely with the fact that the arima_plus model interpolates the missing data, when actually that missing data is supossed to be non sales or zero $ sales. [Some  info here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-explain-forecast)

Comment: Sure, that is the reason why I explained that if you need to work with missing values in a specific way because of your use case, you need to feed the model with a SQL query that solves that missing data according to your needs.

So, in your case, the solution should be a SQL query providing zero values. That way the model does not need to interpolate that data.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, but my question is: the same way the model fills missing data by means of interpolation i wonder if there is an option in the model to fill it with zeros, without having to insert them myself.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no option for that while creating the model.